# How to Conditionally format text in a Card in Power BI

Tags: conditional-formatting, microsoft-powerbi

I have a Card in a power BI Dashboard that that displays roughly 6 unique text attributes depending on the input.

How do I add a separate color to each attribute, for example if the card displays "apple" I want that text to be red.

Answer (score 0):

First I would create a Measure that translates the text results into the appropriate Hex color codes e.g. **"#f0ebc8"**.  The **= SWITCH ( SELECTEDVALUE ( ...** pattern is usually the easiest way to achieve that.

The on the Card's Format settings, I would select the **Data label / Color / Conditional Formatting (tiny, hidden button with a 3-dot icon, to the right of the Color picker)**, choose **Format by / Field Value**, then choose the new color Measure (defined above).

Comment: How exactly would I use this formula:

Test Color = VAR Color = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Color])
Return
SWITCH(TRUE(),
Color = "#FF0000", "Apple" )

This is what I have but its obviously not working

Comment: I was imagining something like: `Test Color = SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE(Table[FruitName]), "Apple",  "#FF0000" )`

Comment: Please find the reference to Microsoft docs here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting#color-formatting-by-field-value 
   And here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax